# Scheme, recursion with constant value

Tags: scheme, tail-recursion

I have previously asked about letrec and tail recursion, 
I have understood better about letrec and tail recursion from answers
my final goal is, with those, going to implement scheme code for equation: 
e.g. **y(i) = x(i) + 2**  , where x(i), y(i) are lists, so those will be tail recursive with i.
now x, y, i will be in the tail recursive routine so for this part code will be:
but 5 will be always same (not recursive), but you can choose this constant number as input parameter , let's say 'constant'

so expected output, e.g. when you try this : (equationFunc 0 3 1 (lambda (x) x) 5)

*it should work like this...((0 1 2) (0+5 1+5 2+5))*

**final expected output : ((0 1 2) (5 6 7))**

because it will calculate the equation  y(i) = x(i) + 5 (with i boundary from 0 to 2 - so that x(i) , y(i) have to be recursion) but not "+ 5". I just couldn't think about what to do with the "+5" in function implement tail recursion routine.

I think code like this.. but yes, it doesn't work...

```
(define equationFunc
 (lambda (start end res func constant)
  (letrec (helper
         (lambda (x i y constant)
           (if (>= i start)
               (helper (cons i (+ x constant))
                       (- i res)
                       (cons (func i) y)
                       0)
               (cons x (cons y '()))
            )              
          )
         )
   (helper '() end '() 0)          
  )))
```

can anyone give advice?

Comment: The question is not at all clear. What's `func` supposed to do? What's the purpose of `a` and `z` in `equationFunc`? because you're _not_ using them in the helper procedure. And if I call the function with these parameters: `(equationFunc 0 3 1 identity 5)` what's the output you expect?

Comment: And by "output" I mean: what will be printed by the interpreter after the procedure is evaluated, don't try to explain in words the result, write _exactly_ the expected outcome as it would be printed on the screen.

Comment: I edited the question, hope it is more clear what I try to do

Answer (score 1):

It's not *that* clear how the "equation" is supposed to be built. My best guess is:

```
(define equationFunc
  (lambda (start end res func constant)
    (letrec ((helper
              (lambda (x i y)
                (if (>= i start)
                    (helper (cons i x)
                            (- i res)
                            (cons (+ (func i) constant) y))
                    (list x y)))))
      (helper '() (- end 1) '()))))
```

Notice that we didn't have to pass along `start`, `end`, `res`, `func` and `constant` as parameters for the `helper` procedure, we only need to pass the values that keep changing in each iteration, namely: `x`, `y` and `i`. It works for the sample input/output shown in the question:

```
(equationFunc 0 3 1 (lambda (x) x) 5)
=> '((0 1 2) (5 6 7))
```

Comment: @user1915570 If this answer was helpful, please don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking on the check mark to its left ;)